# input values not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two input tags within my html but it doesn't allow me to input anything within them. I have no idea what it could be the values of the input when you click on them aren't clickable. If you would paste my code into your IDE or whatever you use try to replicate my issue. Nothing is able to input into the values I am not sure if it has to do with some of the css I have implemented or what.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#box1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://bossfight.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/boss-fight-free-high-quality-stock-images-photos-photography-coffee-cup-glasses-macbook.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#backgroundnav {
  /*background-color: #ADD8E6;*/
  background-color: #989898;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#content {
  height: 600px;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 900;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.navbar {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

#content h1 {
  font-family: 'Cabin';
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: black;
}

#content p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  text-align: center;
}

#left {
  height: 450px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #989898;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 130px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  height: 450px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #D2B48C;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 130px;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 30px;
}

#middle {
  height: 80%;
}

ol li {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

hr {
  width: 115px;
  color: #989898;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  text-align: center;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
}

#about h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  color: steelblue;
}

#aboutleft {
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  position: relative;
  right: 350px;
  top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

#aboutright {
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  position: relative;
  left: 350px;
  bottom: 285px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

#hr1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

#projects h1 {
  color: black;
}

#projects {
  background-color: #99C4D2;
  height: 1300px;
}

.align {
  position: relative;
  left: 129px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

figure {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: serif;
}

#projects h1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 70px;
}

#contact {
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 700px;
}

form {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 130px;
  top: 110px;
}

label {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  width: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

fieldset {
  background-color: white;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

legend {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 9px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="backgroundnav">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="box1">
    <div id="wrap">
      <h1>Peter Nguyen</h1>
      <hr>
      <h1>Web Developer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="color">
    <div id="content">
      <section id="about">
        <h1 id="about">About Me</h1>
        <hr id="hr1">

        <p id="aboutleft">My names Peter and learning how to code and persuing it in education was one of the best decisions I have made. When I am not at work coding and solving complex web application issues, I am at home learning the latest and greatest frameworks.
          One of the best feelings is knowing that you solved an issue. I am extremly easy to get along with and easy to work with which would make me a great addition to any team. Web development is more than just a hobby and career path for me its a
          passion and a way for me to get creative and think outside of the box!
        </p>

        <p id="aboutright">What else do I do besides code? I enjoy barbequing, lifting weights, being outdoors. I am also secretely a nerd so I enjoy playing video games, and reading books. Did I also mention that I enjoy playing ping pong? I was born in California and
          lated move out to Arizona as a young kid growing up. As a kid I had a very high interest in computers and always wondered about the person who created every component a computer has. I beilive that is why to this day I am so intrigued by development.
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>


    <div id="left">
      <h1>Place holder content for future case projects</h1>
      <input type="text" id="case1">
      <input type="text" id="case1x">
    </div>

    <div id="right">
      <h1>Place holcer content for future case projects</h1>
      <input type="number" name="">

    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="projects">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <figure id="link" class="align">
      <a href="https://puu.sh/vIKzj/a98ecf7f9e.png"><img src="image.jpg" alt="Golden Gate Bridge" width="500" height="350"></a>
      <figcaption>
        Guessing game created with JavaScript
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="align">
      <a href="https://puu.sh/vHIlA/29a21ac2de.png"><img src="image.jpg" alt="Golden Gate Bridge" width="500" height="350"></a>
      <figcaption>
        Halong Bay kayak
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="align">
      <a href="http://halongbaycruises.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Plitvice-lakes-chain.jpg"><img src="image.jpg" alt="Golden Gate Bridge" width="500" height="350"></a>
      <figcaption>
        Halong Bay Waterfalls
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="align">
      <a href="http://images.surprisinghalong.com/uploads//2013/11/surprising-cave-ha-long-bay.jpg"><img src="image.jpg" alt="Golden Gate Bridge" width="500" height="350"></a>
      <figcaption>
        Halong Bay Cave
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your projects `<h1>` is sitting on top of your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is differently in css. Open your page in browser then try to inspect input box - you will see that it overlapped by h1 tag. So fix the sizing of h1 -and you will get your input work.

Comment: Thanks I should have inspected it first I thought it was the sizing of the h1 but wasn't sure!

Answer (score 0):

You are making your H1 position relative. In fact, you have a lot of excess relative positioning going on in your CSS. The H1 tag is huge and overlapping most of your page